# What is the best numerical way of solving this Schwinger-Dyson equations?

Tags: condensed-matter, computational-physics, greens-functions

I have to solve these equations numerically

\begin{equation}
\begin{cases}
G(\omega)=\frac{1}{-i\omega-\Sigma(\omega)} \\ \Sigma(\tau)=J^2G(\tau)^2G(-\tau)
\end{cases}
\end{equation}

These are the Schwinger-Dyson equations for the SYK model. In Appendix G of "Comments on the SYK model" by Maldacena and Stanford, they say that this can be done iterating. We can start by using the free Green function

\begin{equation}
G_0(\omega)=-\frac{1}{-i\omega}
\end{equation}

then calculating the self-energy $\Sigma_0(\tau)$ and then iterating using

\begin{equation}
G_n(\omega)=(1-x)G_{n-1}(\omega)+x\frac{1}{-i\omega-\Sigma_{n-1}(\omega)}
\end{equation}

where $x$ is just a parameter to control the iteration. Since this is done using the Matsubara formalism, the frequencies are discrete

\begin{equation}
\omega_n=\frac{\pi(2n+1)}{\beta}
\end{equation}

My problem is twofold. First, I don't know how to deal with the fact that $n\in\mathcal{Z}$ meaning that it goes from $-\infty$ to $\infty$. This would mean that in each step of the iteration I would have to sweep over a lot of different values of $n$ in order to get the new Green function, making the calculation very slow. My second problem is that I don't really know how to perform the Fourier Transform in each step. Mostly because it is actually a Fourier Series and also because of the first problem (I don't know where to cut the $n$ and therefore I don't really know how many terms to add to the Fourier Expansion).

I'm using Mathematica for this but I'm open to other software. I would really like a reference to a paper with methods that apply to this case or any help possible.

P.S.: I know this might be a computational question more than a physics one, but I trully believe that computational calculations and simulations are a part of physics so I think this belongs here more than in a computational or math forum.